# I get the " Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client " error with node-js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm coding the backend of a wbesite for a school project, and i got an error in the likes and dislikes part of my code. I get the " Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" when i try to remove like but when i use promises instead of async in my removeLike function it's working.

```
    async function likeSauce(req, res) {
    if (![1, -1, 0].includes(req.body.like)) {
        return res.status(403).send({ message: "Invalid like value" })
    } else {
        await addLike(req, res)
        await addDislike(req, res)
        await removeLike(req, res)
        await removeDislike(req, res)
    }
}


async function addLike(req, res) {
    if (req.body.like === 1) {
        try {
            await Product.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, { $inc: { likes: 1 }, $push: { usersLiked: req.body.userId } })
            return res.status(200).send({ message: "Like added !" })
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(400).send({ error })
        }
    }
}

async function addDislike(req, res) {
    if (req.body.like === -1) {
        try {
            await Product.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, { $inc: { dislikes: 1 }, $push: { usersDisliked: req.body.userId } })
            return res.status(200).send({ message: "Dislike added !" })
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(400).send({ error })
        }
    }
}


async function removeLike(req, res) {
    const resultat = await Product.findOne({ _id: req.params.id })
    if (resultat.usersLiked.includes(req.body.userId)) {
        try {
            await Product.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, { $inc: { likes: -1 }, $pull: { usersLiked: req.body.userId } })
            return res.status(200).send({ message: "Like removed !" })
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(400).send({ error })
        }
    }
}

async function removeDislike(req, res) {
    const resultat = await Product.findOne({ _id: req.params.id })
    if (resultat.usersDisliked.includes(req.body.userId)) {
        try {
            await Product.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, { $inc: { dislikes: -1 }, $pull: { usersDisliked: req.body.userId } })
            return res.status(200).send({ message: "Dislike removed !" })
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(400).send({ error })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your functions should return values that indicate whether they have sent a response. Once a response has been sent, there's no point calling the other functions.

Comment: You mean in my likeSauce function ? Something like if ( like === 1 ) { addLike(req,res) } and the same for the rest ?

Comment: Right. There are several ways of doing it, but once one of the functions has sent a response, there is no point calling any of the other functions.

Comment: thanx i'll try that

Comment: It's working thanks again for your help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you use await for:

```
await addLike(req, res)
await addDislike(req, res)
await removeLike(req, res)
await removeDislike(req, res)
```

This will instruct node.js to wait for functions completions, but in all of theses functions, you return with a `res.send`.

So after, the first call Express has already send the response, and second function call will générate your error while trying to `res.send`

You must take advantage of Node.js aysnchronous bay using callbak or better promise.

You should `res.send` only once.

promisify your 4 functions and use `then()` and `catch()` to call them. And then call `res.send` only once in the last `then()`.

Also, you should test `like` value before calling functions, doing this you will not call all function, but just the right one.

Comment: At first I did it with promises and it worked well, but I wanted to do it asynchronously without promises because that was what was required

Comment: So you must use a switch or tests on ``req.body.like`` before calling addLike, addDislike, etc. And remove this test from within theses functions.

Answer (score 0):

Always do return res, even in catch section

Comment: okay i add return but it's still not working

Comment: This will not solve the problem.